# Printing all keys and values in a single line after sorting the keys

Tags: json, jq

I've a folder with more than 1000 request logs (generated per hour/day) which are in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "input": {
      "random_param_name_1": "random_value_1",
      "random_param_name_2": "random_value_2",
      "random_param_name_3": "random_value_3",
      "random_param_name_4": "random_value_4"
    },
    "output": {
      "some_key_we_dont_care_about": "some_value_we_dont_care_about"
    },
    "status_code": 200
  },
  {
    "input": {
      "random_param_name_1": "random_value_1",
      "random_param_name_4": "random_value_4",
      "random_param_name_3": "random_value_3",
      "random_param_name_5": "random_value_5"
    },
    "output": {
      "some_key_we_dont_care_about": "some_value_we_dont_care_about"
    },
    "status_code": 200
  }
]
```

And I need to find all the input requests that are unique. For this, I need to do two things:

1. sort the keys in `input` as different inputs might have same keys but in different order
2. print all the key and value in a single line, so that I can pipe the output to `sort | uniq` to get all the unique input combinations.

Please note that the input keys are random, most existing questions in stackoverflow of the similar kind, know the keys in advance, but that's not the case here.

I can print the key and values like this:

```
jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k):(.[$k])"'
```

but they end up being on new lines.

to summarise, for the above json, I need a `magic_expression`

```sh
$ jq 'magic_expression' log.json
```

that will return

```sh
"random_param_name_1":"random_value_1","random_param_name_2":"random_value_2","random_param_name_3":"random_value_3","random_param_name_4":"random_value_4"
"random_param_name_1":"random_value_1","random_param_name_3":"random_value_3","random_param_name_4":"random_value_4","random_param_name_5":"random_value_5"
```

Comment: Why not let jq find the unique requests for you?  It's trivial in jq.  It might also make sense to produce the results as JSON - would you want one JSON per line in that case?  If uniqueness is guaranteed for you, would you still want the keys to be sorted?

Comment: @peak, I have mentioned that i need *unique* inputs and I have included the expected output, which I believe is sufficient to know if status and output are required. Btw, good to know you have that link handy with you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a "magic expression" to get you started.
It uses [`to_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) to make the objects appearing in `.input` more managable.

```
def format: "\"\(.key)\":\"\(.value)\"" ;
map(.input) | unique | map(to_entries)[] | map(format) | join(",")
```

When run with [`-r`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) / [`--raw-output`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) it produces

```
"random_param_name_1":"random_value_1","random_param_name_2":"random_value_2","random_param_name_3":"random_value_3","random_param_name_4":"random_value_4"
"random_param_name_1":"random_value_1","random_param_name_4":"random_value_4","random_param_name_3":"random_value_3","random_param_name_5":"random_value_5"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xZDBTsMwDIbvfYrIp1Ya0@i2S3mUdYrM6kkdJO7ShGkCnj14aTlAx04gDpHs359/xf/hGGNDe7VnZ9BXCmqo8/kTnYsaqlS/4HMg6UA9ZAa7fN7aLvhCvalg22MgKS6yZ03Wu5b6YrMdtcH0gh64tTnMoIhxkyn1Kk8pSE5Qja0IDm3DRnfo0GiLhvS9jD/l9BNRZj/j5QQvb@HLCb68ha8m@AoS/T4sAQf/7aKeZU/i1CfSDVuvd@hI4yMnbBgPVleAL969Rx96veOGZLNcLLJx9mdhXjv398JcT/D1P4eZbeOd@wA)

EDIT: if as [customcommander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1244884/customcommander) points out you want the keys to be sorted you can move the `format` before the `unique`.  e.g.

```
def format: "\"\(.key)\":\"\(.value)\"" ;
map(.input | to_entries | map(format) | sort ) | unique[] | join(",")
```

which produces

```
"random_param_name_1":"random_value_1","random_param_name_2":"random_value_2","random_param_name_3":"random_value_3","random_param_name_4":"random_value_4"
"random_param_name_1":"random_value_1","random_param_name_3":"random_value_3","random_param_name_4":"random_value_4","random_param_name_5":"random_value_5"
```

when run with [`-r`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) / [`--raw-output`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xZDPTsMwDMbvfQrLp1Ya0@i2S3mUdYrC6kkdJO7yB4SAZw9eOg7QsROIQyR//n624u9wTKmjPezZGR0awBbbcv5AL1WLTa6f9GMkUQh3hdFDOe/tEAO8QWBFNrievIiTM@6oRHl2AU5FtP0x0mYr5YF7W@IMq5Q2BcCrPADMy7A5S2k4bTs2atBOG2W1IXUr9mc7f0Y6s5/xeoLX1/DlBF9ew1cTfIWZfh@HkGP4dpFnmZNE1TOpjm1QO@1I6XvO2GiPqy4AX3b7oEP0ascdyWS9WBRn78/CvHTu74W5nuDrfw6z2KYb9wE)

Comment: I think the OP also wanted the keys to be sorted. So in the second line, `random_param_3` should come before `random_param_4`.

Comment: Good point - I've updated my response to include a version which does that.

Comment: Is it worth documenting how jq is invoked? I guess that output is only possible with `-r` isn't it?

Comment: I added a link to the docs - always good for folks new to `jq` who come along later.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
/workspaces # jq 'map(.input)' data.json 
[
  {
    "random_param_name_1": "random_value_1",
    "random_param_name_2": "random_value_2",
    "random_param_name_3": "random_value_3",
    "random_param_name_4": "random_value_4"
  },
  {
    "random_param_name_1": "random_value_1",
    "random_param_name_4": "random_value_4",
    "random_param_name_3": "random_value_3",
    "random_param_name_5": "random_value_5"
  }
]
```

You can sort the keys of each object with `--sort-keys`:

```
/workspaces # jq --sort-keys 'map(.input)' data.json 
[
  {
    "random_param_name_1": "random_value_1",
    "random_param_name_2": "random_value_2",
    "random_param_name_3": "random_value_3",
    "random_param_name_4": "random_value_4"
  },
  {
    "random_param_name_1": "random_value_1",
    "random_param_name_3": "random_value_3",
    "random_param_name_4": "random_value_4",
    "random_param_name_5": "random_value_5"
  }
]
```

Then pipe this into another jq filter:

```
/workspaces # jq --sort-keys 'map(.input)' data.json | jq -r 'map(to_entries)[] | map("\"\(.key)\":\"\(.value)\"") | join(",")'
"random_param_name_1":"random_value_1","random_param_name_2":"random_value_2","random_param_name_3":"random_value_3","random_param_name_4":"random_value_4"
"random_param_name_1":"random_value_1","random_param_name_3":"random_value_3","random_param_name_4":"random_value_4","random_param_name_5":"random_value_5"
```

Comment: +1 for [`--sort-keys / -S`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq).  With that you can probably do it all in one filter.

Comment: @jq170727 I'd be interested to see that :) Please show me.

Comment: I thought with -r and -S [`map(.input | to_entries | map("\"\(.key)\":\"\(.value)\"") ) | unique[] | join(",")`](https://tio.run/##xZCxjsIwDIb3PkXkqZUAcQUWXuNGiixDPRSuSUmTO53gnj2YFAYoMB1isGT7//xL/je7EGpq0lGlG@/UQTmDrJ2tuJXhpEABRTra8m9WwDz23/TlWSbIVCaQ19XO82Ip7cZUOoUBZCEsEqX2UkpBtIb5eZSFJV2aGhuyVKOmmvFD5Ms62stm8BjPe3j@DJ/08MkzfNrDpxDpv@4IjHc3H7VG7iQj/GEsjXa4JstIKxOxTu6s7gBX3q0j51tcm5LlMh@Pk7P2sjDvvft/Yc56@OzNYSbLMLRh@HkE "jq – Try It Online") would work but apparently it doesn't.  The `sort` is still needed even with -S.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to find all the input requests that are unique.

This can be done within jq, without any sorting of keys, since jq's == operator ignores the key order.  For example, the following will produce the unique input requests in their original form (i.e. without the keys being sorted):

```
map(.input)
| group_by(.)
| map(.[0])
```

Since `group_by` uses `==`, uniqueness is guaranteed.

If you really want the keys to be sorted, then you could use the -S command-line option:

jq -S -f program.jq input.json

And if for some reason you really want the non-standard output format, you could use the following modification of the above program:

```
map(.input)
| group_by(.)
| map(.[0])
| .[]
| . as $in
| [ keys[] as $k | "\"\($k)\":\"\($in[$k])\"" ] | join(",")
```

With your sample input, this last produces:

```
"random_param_name_1":"random_value_1","random_param_name_2":"random_value_2","random_param_name_3":"random_value_3","random_param_name_4":"random_value_4"
"random_param_name_1":"random_value_1","random_param_name_3":"random_value_3","random_param_name_4":"random_value_4","random_param_name_5":"random_value_5"
```